# Asterisk - Send voicemail to email as client SMTP address

Tags: linux, email, asterisk, elastix

I'm able to setup Elastix (Asterisk) to send email voicemail attachments without any issue. But I'm trying to email them to a particular external address and it seems to be rejecting the emails as they are coming from root@.com

I have an SMTP address I can validate through (voicemail@.com) but I cannot seem to find a way to make Elastix send emails as a client.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your mail server to rewrite the sender address. On postfix, this can be done [this](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic) way:

1. Add your domain as `mydomain` on postfix main.cf and enable generic maps in postfix main.cf:

`postconf -e 'mydomain = example.com'`

`postconf -e 'smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic'`

2. Put the rewrite rule in `/etc/postfix/generic`:

   `root@example.com       voicemail@example.com`
3. Run postmap:
   `postmap /etc/postfix/generic`
4. Reload postfix:
   `postfix reload`

Comment: Thanks, this helped change the from address, but it seems to remote mail server is still rejecting or blocking these emails. I was really hoping there would be a way to authenticate as a client and then send the messages that way.