# Postfix with external SMTP

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, request-tracker

I'm trying to install Request Tracker and configure it to use an external SMTP server to sent mail notifications. I've already put postfix to send emails using [this tutorial](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/), but it keeps sending then as apache@mail.com or root@mail.com and not through the mail account reserve to this. I want to change it to use something like noreply@mycompany.com because a rule will be set on the server to block this kind of emails. Does anyone has any tip for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postfix [sender address rewrite feature](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic). I answered a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/655705/19440)

Comment: It works partially. Looking to the mail header the sender is correct, but the destination continue wrong... the email has been sent sometimes to root@correio.company.com and sometimes to leandro@correio.company.com... It never gets the destination from the RT